# SMEStorage with Dropbox on the iPad

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, iwork, dropbox

I was looking around for ways to get my iWork documents from iWork into Dropbox; going through a forum post on the dropbox website I came accross [SMEStroage](http://smestorage.com/?p=static&page=faq#DropBox) do any of you use this? If how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SMEStorage](http://smestorage.com/) is a cloud storage service, similar to DropBox itself. In the scenario you are referring to, you can use the SME Storage API directly to upload to an external file provider like DropBox.

Effectively like DropBox you can store everything on the SMEStorage Servers and then access it from any OS/Device as long as you have an internet connection.

From reading the documentation it is really a more advanced DropBox service, which allows developers to use their API to have a central point for accessing various storage options.

From what I can determine, like iCloud, the application needs to support the actual API and interface to be able to store data through it, and since iWorks on iOS only supports iCloud, I am not sure if it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use SMEStorage to edit and save my DropBox, Google Docs and SkyDrive documents with iWork on iPhone and iPad (although it support many other Clouds).

If you buy the SMEStorage iOS App (called iSMEStorage) then you can add the Clouds to it that you want to use with iWork (or any other WebDav client)  to the App and when you launch iWork you use the URL https://WebDAV.SMEStorage.com to then access your Cloud files in iWork.

Clouds added to your SMEStorage Account are WebDav enabled by an access layer that SMEStorage refer to as CloudDav.

Answer (score 0):

Can validate that SMEStorage will enable you to not only access your DropBox Docs directly in iWork but also edit and save them. To add to the previous answer by Carl, you don't need to purchase iSMEStorage to get this feature, you can sign up for a free account and pay a one time $5 fee for the CloudDav product (http://smestorage.com/?p=static&page=CloudDav)